# Is it possible to .complete() a CompletableFuture<?> with an Object?

Tags: java, generics, completable-future

Is it possible to call `complete()` in this context at runtime where the class used for the `CompletableFuture` is unknown at the time of completion?

It's already guaranteed that object provided will be of the correct class. But I don't thnk that I can actually call `complete()` here without an explicit cast.

I'v already started to explore alternative ways to approach this as I'm assuming that it's not possible to do this. But I thought I'd asked on StackOverflow just in case.

```
Map<String, CompletableFuture<?>> map = new HashMap<>();

map.put("identifier1", new CompletableFuture<Integer>());
map.put("identifier2", new CompletableFuture<String>());

Object object = new Integer(1);

// Cannot explicitly cast (Integer) as the original generic value is unknown at runtime
map.get("identifier1").complete(object);
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  Why not just call `complete()` on an `Integer` object, which is what you declared in the diamond to begin with?

Comment: You can use an unsafe cast to `CompletableFuture<Object>`. The warning means that doing so can cause `ClassCastException` to be raised at a point where no explicit cast is performed in your code.

Comment: One more comment: The casting error you are getting is one reason why generics were introduced.  There is no guarantee that the `Object` you are trying to complete will be of the correct type.

Comment: Why don't you use a `Map<String, CompletableFuture<Object>>`? If it has to do with how you create the map, add it to the question as well.

Comment: You cannot cast or convert an `CompletableFuture<Integer>` to a `CompletableFuture<Object>`.

Comment: There is no point in putting `CompletableFuture<Integer>` in the map in your example. Just put `CompletableFuture<Object>` and you'll be fine. I thus assumed this is not really how you create your map, and you are actually doing something else with the futures when creating them that would be useful to show as well. Sorry if my previous comment wasn't clear.